# Upload video/image file data in node.js and store it in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, image, express, video

**I want to store Image/Video data that user posts into a mongoDB database but it is getting saved as an empty array.**

The Multer Configuration:

```
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: "./uploads/",
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(
      null,
      file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)
    );
  },
});
const upload = multer({
  storage,
}).array("media");

module.exports = upload;
```

The createPost route to upload a new post that can be type of anything like plain-text, Images or videos[Media]:

```
exports.createPost = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
    if (!user) return res.status(401).json({ message: "No user found" });
    const { media, hashTags, postStatus } = req.body;

    const mentions = await User.find(
      { User_name: req.body.mentions },
      { User_name: 1, _id: 0 }
    );

    if (
      req.body.mentions &&
      (!Array.isArray(mentions) || mentions.length === 0)
    ) {
      return res.status(404).send("Please enter valid user name");
    }

    let payLoad = {
      userId: req.user._id,
      media,
      hashTags,
      postStatus,
    };

    if (mentions.length > 0) {
      payLoad = { ...payLoad, mentions };
    }

    let new_post = await new Post(payLoad).save();
    return res.status(200).send(new_post);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send(error.message);
  }
};
```

**When I pass plain-text in media attribute then It is saved to the database but when I pass image or video from postman form-data then the media is getting saved as an empty array**

The API endpoint:

```
router.post("/createPost", auth, storage, post.createPost);
```

Can anyone assist me here?

Comment: The file data is available in `req.files` and not `req.body` as mentioned in the document [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).

Comment: I have tried it. And it is not working @ĐăngKhoaĐinh